# JFileChooser does not display window in Mac

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code for an application. I used it in Ubuntu and it worked fine. But when I try to run it in macOS with the same java version, it has some problems. The first JFileChooser opens up and works fine. But the second JFileChooser is not displayed.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String segmentedImageDir="", segmentedImageSuffix="", originalImageDir="";
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        fc.setDialogTitle("Select Original Images Directory");
        System.out.println("Getting Original Images Directory");
        if(fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            originalImageDir = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        }
        System.out.println("Original Images Directory: "+originalImageDir);
        fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        fc.setDialogTitle("Select Segmented Images Directory");
        System.out.println("Getting Segmented Images Directory");
        //Everything works fine till here
        if(fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            segmentedImageDir = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        }
        System.out.println("Segmented Images Directory: "+segmentedImageDir);

        segmentedImageSuffix = MainFrame.getSegmentedImageSuffix();

        try{
            new MainFrame(originalImageDir, segmentedImageDir, segmentedImageSuffix);
        } catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not load image", "IOException", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be some buggy weirdness on macs. However, I found an easy fix for you:

There is no actual need to make another instance of JFileChooser here; you can simply delete this line:

```
fc = new JFileChooser();
```

and leave everything else, and now it'll pop up the file chooser dialog in directory mode twice, properly titled, just as you want.

This [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8133613) seems to indicate, even though that was not reproducible according to someone at oracle, that this bug has been in there for a while.